# Custom Meta Boxes and Fields for WordPress: Change directory upload based on user-edit page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, meta-boxes

I am using the [CMB script (Custom Meta Boxes and Fields for WordPress)](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/tree/trunk) for uploading files for different users that have the custom role of `cliente`.

I am able to show the fields and make them work (though they only appear when editing a user, and not when creating it, but this is for another question). What I am trying to achieve now is to upload files to different folders for different users.

Here is the code:

```
// Here we add a new user role, "cliente"
add_role( 'cliente', 'Cliente' );

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_upload_prefilter');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'my_upload_postfilter');

function my_upload_prefilter( $file ) {
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'custom_upload_dir');
    return $file;
}

function my_upload_postfilter( $fileinfo ) {
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'custom_upload_dir');
    return $fileinfo;
}

function custom_upload_dir( $path ) {
    global $pagenow;

    // Check if we are on the user-edit.php page
    if ( $pagenow == 'user-edit.php' && isset($_GET['user_id']) ) {
        // Set the role we want to change the path for
        $role_to_check = 'cliente';
        // Get a bunch of user info for later use
        $user_id = filter_var( $_GET['user_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        $meta = get_user_meta($user_id);
        $roles = unserialize($meta['wp_capabilities'][0]);
        // If we are on the chosen role page, set the $customdir to first_name + last_name
        if ( !empty($roles[$role_to_check]) ) {
            $customdir = '/' . $meta['first_name'][0] . $meta['last_name'][0];
        }
    } else {
        // Here we are not on the user-edit.php page. This is just a check to prove that WP is not recognizing the correct page, maybe because we are doing an Ajax call when this function is called. Confusing.
        $customdir = '/did-not-work';
    }

    // If there is any error, just return the $path and abort the rest.
    if ( !empty( $path['error'] ) ) {
        return $path;
    }

    // Here we set the new $path with the $customdir set above
    $path['path']    = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['path']); //remove default subdir (year/month)
    $path['url']     = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['url']);      
    $path['subdir']  = $customdir;
    $path['path']   .= $customdir; 
    $path['url']    .= $customdir; 
    return $path;

}
```

From a few checks I have run it seems like my code does retrieve the user id and the data stored in the db, but it does not detect it when uploading the images. Might this be related to the fact that we are uploading images via Ajax or something like that?

Just to be clear, I don't want the upload based on the current logged in user, but on the user I, as a super-admin, am editing using the edit-user.php page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wait a second, does that mean that **while** you're uploading a file (through AJAX) you **can't** retrieve any other information? (.. Through another ajax request?..)

Comment: I don't know. It was just a guess. The data gets retrieved when checking on the page (I did several var_dumps in different circumstances), but when uploading via Ajax the `if ( $pagenow == 'user-edit.php' && isset($_GET['user_id']) )` statements fails and the file is uploaded to the folder `/did-not-work`.

Comment: have you tried logging (echoing) both $_GET['user_id'] and $pagenow? just to know if the problem is in the GET request or in the $pagenow variable.

Comment: Yes, I did and both log as expected: `user-edit.php` and the user_id that is being edited. But these do not get send when uploading files thus resulting in the `$customdir` variable being set to `/did-not-work`. I guess it might be due to when and how hooks are called by WordPress, but I don't know how to debug them.

Comment: Yes, then you should rather check why they are not being sent. Where is your upload script called from?

Comment: If you are familiar with WordPress, we are on the edit-user.php page, which is when you go edit an existing user. Using [cmb](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/tree/trunk) and the script you can find on [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/GioSensation/cdccbd75d1779b873ca1), an upload button appears on the user-edit page. When clicked, the standard WordPress file-upload dialog gets triggered. Everything works just fine, but I am not able to send files to the desired folder, because the `add_filter` I created does not detect that we are on `edit-user.php`

Comment: I'm not that familiar with wordpress, but I've made several time somes many upload forms. The best thing you can do is check the add_filter function then or, **into the original cmb**, edit the printed form by passing an additional parameter that you may get from the above script.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was thinking about something like that, too. Just hoped the cmb devs would notice this and offer some easy fix without hacking their script. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any fix though. I wish I could put a bounty on this topic to make it more relevant but you apparently don't yet have enough reputation to do such. I will keep looking around anyway, maybe we can find an easier solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. First the correct code, then an explaination:

```
// Here we add a new user role, "cliente".
add_role( 'cliente', 'Cliente' );

// These are the filters we need to add in order to modify the default upload path.
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_upload_prefilter');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'my_upload_postfilter');

function my_upload_prefilter( $file ) {
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'custom_upload_dir');
    return $file;
}
function my_upload_postfilter( $fileinfo ) {
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'custom_upload_dir');
    return $fileinfo;
}

function custom_upload_dir( $path ) {
    // When uploading, the file gets sent to upload_async.php, so we need to take the referral page in order to be able to get the user_id we need. We then take the query string, pass it through parse_str and store it in a $query_array. Took me a while to figure it out, but now it works like a charm.
    $actual_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    parse_str( parse_url($actual_page, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query_array );

    // Check if we are uploading from the user-edit.php page.
    if ( strpos($actual_page, 'user-edit.php') ) {
        // Set the role we want to change the path for.
        $role_to_check = 'cliente';
        // Get a bunch of user info for later use
        $user_id = filter_var( $query_array['user_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        $meta = get_user_meta( $user_id );
        $roles = unserialize( $meta['wp_capabilities'][0] );
        // If we are on the chosen role page, set the $customdir to first_name + last_name
        if ( !empty($roles[$role_to_check]) ) {
            $customdir = '/docs/' . $meta['first_name'][0] . $meta['last_name'][0];

            // If there is any error, just return the $path and abort the rest.
            if ( !empty( $path['error'] ) ) {
                return $path;
            }

            // Here we set the new $path with the $customdir set above
            $new_subdir = $customdir . $path['subdir'];
            $path['path']    = str_replace( $path['subdir'], $new_subdir, $path['path'] );
            $path['url']     = str_replace( $path['subdir'], $new_subdir, $path['url'] );
            $path['subdir']  = $new_subdir;
            return $path;
        }
    } else {
        // We are not uploading from user-edit.php, so go ahead as per default.
        return $path;
    }
}
```

The problem was that when uploading via Ajax, `$pagenow` correctly stores the `async-upload.php` page, rather than the url we're in. I simply had to retrieve the referral page via php `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (please, note that the `referer` typo is there because of a legacy typo in the http spec, funny stuff).

Please also note that the PHP specs discourage the use of `HTTP_REFERER` because it could yield unexpected results based on server configurations, but in this case I should have full control over the server, so it should not be a problem. If you encounter any issue, I would suggest to check that out.

Once I have the correct url I am able to parse it and check if we are on `user-edit.php`, if we are, get the `user_id` from the query string and proceed from there.

Took me a while to figure it out, but in hindsight it was quite easy.

Hope it helps somebody else in the future.